# Display resolution accepted terminal a not all acceptes by adding to gui

Tags: debian, linux-mint, resolution, laptop-display

I know of two ways to set the resolution of a notebook LVDS display higher than its physical resolution.

Both variants work in general, but I can't set a screen resolution as high as the one that allows to change the resolution beyond a reboot (configuration via `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/45custom_xrandr-settings` file).

The two methods of adjustment known to me differ among other things in the fact that in one method the desired picture frequency and line frequency (or the video frequency ?) is indicated.

How can I adapt the procedure which in the example does not allow me such a high display resolution, so that the display resolution is as high as the variant which allows a higher screen resolution.

Physical resolution of LVDS sample display:

```
 * 1280×800
```

Possible resolution of vga/display
Question by Terminal: `xrandr -q`
Output by terminal: `minimum 320 x 200, current 1280x800 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384`

In the example, the resolutions can be easily adjusted using the terminal:

```
xrandr –output LVDS-1 –mode 1280×800 –panning 1440×900 –scale 1.125×1.125
xrandr –output LVDS-1 –mode 1280×800 –panning 1680×1050 –scale 1,3125×1,3125
xrandr –output LVDS-1 –mode 1280×800 –panning 1920×1200 –scale 1.5×1.5
xrandr –output LVDS-1 –mode 1280×800 –panning 2560×1600 –scale 2.0x2.0
```

Created values for gui by follow way:

```
# working
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --verbose --addmode LVDS-1 "1440x900_60.00"
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode "1440x900_60.00"

# working
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --verbose --addmode LVDS-1 "1680x1050_60.00"
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode "1680x1050_60.00"

# not working
xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --verbose --addmode LVDS-1 "1920x1200_60.00"
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode "1920x1200_60.00"

# not working
xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_46.00"  144.25  1920 2032 2232 2544  1200 1203 1209 1235 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --verbose --addmode LVDS-1 "1920x1200_46.00"
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode "1920x1200_46.00"

# not working
xrandr --newmode "2560x1600_60.00"  348.50  2560 2760 3032 3504  1600 1603 1609 1658 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --verbose --addmode LVDS-1 "2560x1600_60.00"
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode "2560x1600_60.00"

# not working
xrandr --newmode "2560x1600_27.00"  146.00  2560 2680 2944 3328  1600 1603 1609 1628 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --verbose --addmode LVDS-1 "2560x1600_27.00"
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode "2560x1600_27.00"
```

How did the values created for gui file:
xrandr

Determine values for desired new, non-existent resolution vertical frequency:

```
cvt 1440 900 60
```

Output:

```
1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz
Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

Add the new mode:

```
xrandr --verbose --addmode default "1440x900_60.00"
xrandr --verbose --delmode default "1440x900_60.00"
```

Create file for add the new resolution to gui:

```
sudo xed /etc/X11/Xsession.d/45custom_xrandr-settings
```

Working fine by new by me created resolutions, available by gui:

```
1440×900
1680×1050
```

Resolutions which dont work by my added gui resolution, a working fine by changing by me by terminal. **How to be successful to create the follow resolutions also by gui ?**

```
1920×1200
2560×1600
```

Just my two cents:
Yes of cource, it can be its not possible to configure on my way on sudo xed /etc/X11/Xsession.d/45custom_xrandr-settings depend on Frame rate, line rate or pixel clock. A remember, this resolutions ( 1920×1200; 2560×1600) is very well adjustable via xrand like follow by terminal:

```
xrandr –output LVDS-1 –mode 1280×800 –panning 1920×1200 –scale 1.5×1.5
xrandr –output LVDS-1 –mode 1280×800 –panning 2560×1600 –scale 2.0x2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow solution, which working fine by known panel datas by data sheet:**

**Its looks cvt supports on by me used way:**

- the resolution of display
- and the refresh rate p.e. 6oHz

**A its looks the cvt by terminal dont support on my used way:**

- the min and max horizontal sync rate of display
- the min and max pixel clock of display.

**The follow counter on website are a better way for calculate display configuration file:**

- http://xtiming.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xtiming.pl

**The for calculating is to know the follow data from used display:**

- Horizontal Sync Rate:
  The number of scan lines (visible and invisible) that are drawn on the screen per second.   kHz min kHz max
- Refresh Rate:
  Also known as the Vertical Sync Rate, this is the number of screen refreshes per second.    Hz min Hz max
- Dot Clock Frequency :
  Also known as the Pixel Clock, this is the speed at which pixels are drawn on the screen.

**The problem is now:**

- how to get the display data by linux terminal or
- how to get the display data from notebook vendor
- or how to get the display data from panel vendor ?

**Typical panel vendor are p.e:**

- AUO
- Chi Mei Optoelectronics
- Samsung
- Hannstar
- Toshiba
- LG Display
- Sharp
- Hydis Hundai